# fixed position div doesn't fade out

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I got an issue with the jQuery fade out function on Internet Explorer.

As you can see on this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2ZGfL/), it doesn't fade out on any version of internet explorer.

But I noticed it's only when a div has a fixed position (`position:fixed;`)

Is there any workaround?

You can reproduce the bug with this code

```
   <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $('.goBack').click( function(){   
                    $('#about').fadeOut(1000, function ()
                    {
                        $('#backend').fadeOut("slow");
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="backend">
            <div id="about">
                <div class="leftPanel">
                    <h1>About</h1>
                    <div class="menu">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Menu1</li>
                            <li>Menu2</li>
                            <li>Menu3</li>
                            <li>Menu3</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="goBack">
                        <p>Go Back</p>
                    </div>
               </div>   
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

with this CSS

```
.leftPanel
{
    position:fixed;
    color:black;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

demo doesn't use enough css for `fixed`. Apply `position:relative` to parent and provide `top` &`left` and it works fine

```css
#about{position:relative}

.leftPanel
{
    position:fixed;
     top:0;left:0;
 }
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/2ZGfL/1/

Comment: Thank you so much. What an easy solution. But I don't understand why it wouldn't work without. I thought the default value was `position:relative;`

Comment: Also, it works in ie7 and ie9 but in ie8 there's no fade effect. Do you have any idea why? Thank you

Comment: can't say...only time I use `fixed` is with higher level elements usually related to or window position or scrolling. Likely find IE bug info in a google search

Answer (score 0):

Try placing your Script tag after body tag or before end of body tag..

```
<body> 
    ........
    ........
    <script>

     // JQuery Script

    </script>
 </body>
```

Comment: what does placement of script tag have to do with code shown? Is wrapped in `ready` handler

Answer (score 0):

Try using a setTimeout function... something like this...

```
setTimeout(function(){$("#about").fadeOut("fast");},2000);
```

It might work...

And also try using position: absolute or relative...

Answer (score 0):

No need to change your css. This will work:

```
$(function() {
$('.goBack').click( function(){   
  $(this).parent($('#backend')).fadeOut(1000);
});
});
```